# How to make a VESA linear frame buffer in real mode to use it after in protected mode?

Tags: assembly, x86, operating-system, protected-mode, vesa

I want to create a small operating system, but in 32-bit mode with graphics with the full resolution of my screen (1366x768) and 24 bpp.
For now, my code in nasm assembly calls the 0x4F02 VESA function in real mode with the value of 0xC118 (the second bit from left is 1 to create a linear frame buffer). After, I enter in 32-bit protected mode and I can only access the first 64Kb of the screen in 0xA0000, so the linear frame buffer hasn't been created.
And I can't switch bank because it is in protected mode.
I have searched in many sites, but I have not found any way to create a linear frame buffer that works.

Comment: The LFB isn't created at 0xA0000. You need to call 0x4F01 "Return VBE Mode Information" to find out where the LFB is.

Comment: LFB is wherever the call to 0x4F01 said physbase was (same physical address), just map it into virtual memory.

Comment: How do you know that?

Comment: The LFB is not in any place in memory, because I have filled all the memory from 0x100000 with 0xff, and the screen remains black.

Comment: harold was right! I did the call and it said that the physbase was 0xfd000000, and I filled that space with colors and it worked!

Comment: I have just tried that almost 2 years later xd

Comment: Thanks a lot for this discussion, I found mine at 0xE0000000.